# Parsing messy Skim bookmarks plist converted to xml

Tags: ruby, xml, pdf

I'm using the Skim pdf viewer.

You can search bookmarks via a dropdown menu:

[image]

I read in [another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17272/180817) that Skim keeps it locked away in a plist:

```
~/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.skim-app.skim.bookmarks.plist
```

So I converted this file into an xml file by following along with a [blog post](http://osxdaily.com/2016/03/10/convert-plist-file-xml-binary-mac-os-x-plutil/):

```
plutil -convert xml1 bookmarks.plist
```

Please see below for the full dump.

Now, I'm trying to deal with this xml without making a huge mess. I've tried using `active_support` and was able to dig down and find my bookmarks:

```
[3] pry(main)> require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
=> true
[5] pry(main)> h = Hash.from_xml(File.read('bookmarks.plist'))
[39] pry(main)> h['plist']['dict']['array'].first['dict'].each {|h| puts "#{h['integer']} : #{h['string'].first}" }
0 : some info about foobar
386 : some important bookmark about migrations
389 : some important note about anatomy of migrations
158 : cat
```

Is there a better way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>bookmarks</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>_BDAlias</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAGaAAIAAAhVbnRpdGxlZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADU
            QCbVSCsAAABwgnQIc29tZS5wZGYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCW
            8dTPxIpQREYgAAAAAP////8AAAkgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEHBk
            Zm1pbmVyX3Rlc3RpbmcAEAAIAADUQIlFAAAAEQAIAADU0DUKAAAA
            AQAYAHCCdAAPmYwAD5dgAA+WSAAGLMUAAmb9AAIAQ1VudGl0bGVk
            OlVzZXJzOgBtYXg6AERyb3Bib3g6AHdvcms6AHRtcDoAcGRmbWlu
            ZXJfdGVzdGluZzoAc29tZS5wZGYAAA4AEgAIAHMAbwBtAGUALgBw
            AGQAZgAPABIACABVAG4AdABpAHQAbABlAGQAEgA0VXNlcnMvbWF4
            L0Ryb3Bib3gvd29yay90bXAvcGRmbWluZXJfdGVzdGluZy9zb21l
            LnBkZgATAAEvAAAVAAIACv//AAA=
            </data>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>some info about foobar</string>
            <key>pageIndex</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>bookmark</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>_BDAlias</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAFOAAIAAAhVbnRpdGxlZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADU
            QCbVSCsAAABZDB8JYWdpbGUucGRmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCb
            LdTPyHJQREYgAAAAAP////8AAAkgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABi5U
            cmFzaAAQAAgAANRAiUUAAAARAAgAANTQOPIAAAABAAwAWQwfAAYs
            xQACZv0AAgAmVW50aXRsZWQ6VXNlcnM6AG1heDoALlRyYXNoOgBh
            Z2lsZS5wZGYADgAUAAkAYQBnAGkAbABlAC4AcABkAGYADwASAAgA
            VQBuAHQAaQB0AGwAZQBkABIAGlVzZXJzL21heC8uVHJhc2gvYWdp
            bGUucGRmABMAAS8AABUAAgAK//8AAA==
            </data>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>some important bookmark about migrations</string>
            <key>pageIndex</key>
            <integer>386</integer>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>bookmark</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>_BDAlias</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAFOAAIAAAhVbnRpdGxlZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADU
            QCbVSCsAAABZDB8JYWdpbGUucGRmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCb
            LdTPyHJQREYgAAAAAP////8AAAkgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABi5U
            cmFzaAAQAAgAANRAiUUAAAARAAgAANTQOPIAAAABAAwAWQwfAAYs
            xQACZv0AAgAmVW50aXRsZWQ6VXNlcnM6AG1heDoALlRyYXNoOgBh
            Z2lsZS5wZGYADgAUAAkAYQBnAGkAbABlAC4AcABkAGYADwASAAgA
            VQBuAHQAaQB0AGwAZQBkABIAGlVzZXJzL21heC8uVHJhc2gvYWdp
            bGUucGRmABMAAS8AABUAAgAK//8AAA==
            </data>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>some important note about anatomy of migrations</string>
            <key>pageIndex</key>
            <integer>389</integer>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>bookmark</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>_BDAlias</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAGeAAIAAAhVbnRpdGxlZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADU
            QCbVSCsAAABwgnQJYWdpbGUucGRmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHDV
            PNTP2+YAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAkgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEHBk
            Zm1pbmVyX3Rlc3RpbmcAEAAIAADUQIlFAAAAEQAIAADU0ExmAAAA
            AQAYAHCCdAAPmYwAD5dgAA+WSAAGLMUAAmb9AAIARFVudGl0bGVk
            OlVzZXJzOgBtYXg6AERyb3Bib3g6AHdvcms6AHRtcDoAcGRmbWlu
            ZXJfdGVzdGluZzoAYWdpbGUucGRmAA4AFAAJAGEAZwBpAGwAZQAu
            AHAAZABmAA8AEgAIAFUAbgB0AGkAdABsAGUAZAASADVVc2Vycy9t
            YXgvRHJvcGJveC93b3JrL3RtcC9wZGZtaW5lcl90ZXN0aW5nL2Fn
            aWxlLnBkZgAAEwABLwAAFQACAAr//wAA
            </data>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>cat</string>
            <key>pageIndex</key>
            <integer>158</integer>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>bookmark</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>recentDocuments</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>_BDAlias</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAGeAAIAAAhVbnRpdGxlZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADU
            QCbVSCsAAABwgnQJYWdpbGUucGRmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHDV
            PNTP2+YAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAkgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEHBk
            Zm1pbmVyX3Rlc3RpbmcAEAAIAADUQIlFAAAAEQAIAADU0ExmAAAA
            AQAYAHCCdAAPmYwAD5dgAA+WSAAGLMUAAmb9AAIARFVudGl0bGVk
            OlVzZXJzOgBtYXg6AERyb3Bib3g6AHdvcms6AHRtcDoAcGRmbWlu
            ZXJfdGVzdGluZzoAYWdpbGUucGRmAA4AFAAJAGEAZwBpAGwAZQAu
            AHAAZABmAA8AEgAIAFUAbgB0AGkAdABsAGUAZAASADVVc2Vycy9t
            YXgvRHJvcGJveC93b3JrL3RtcC9wZGZtaW5lcl90ZXN0aW5nL2Fn
            aWxlLnBkZgAAEwABLwAAFQACAAr//wAA
            </data>
            <key>pageIndex</key>
            <integer>38</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>_BDAlias</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAGaAAIAAAhVbnRpdGxlZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADU
            QCbVSCsAAABwgnQIc29tZS5wZGYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCW
            8dTPxIpQREYgAAAAAP////8AAAkgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEHBk
            Zm1pbmVyX3Rlc3RpbmcAEAAIAADUQIlFAAAAEQAIAADU0DUKAAAA
            AQAYAHCCdAAPmYwAD5dgAA+WSAAGLMUAAmb9AAIAQ1VudGl0bGVk
            OlVzZXJzOgBtYXg6AERyb3Bib3g6AHdvcms6AHRtcDoAcGRmbWlu
            ZXJfdGVzdGluZzoAc29tZS5wZGYAAA4AEgAIAHMAbwBtAGUALgBw
            AGQAZgAPABIACABVAG4AdABpAHQAbABlAGQAEgA0VXNlcnMvbWF4
            L0Ryb3Bib3gvd29yay90bXAvcGRmbWluZXJfdGVzdGluZy9zb21l
            LnBkZgATAAEvAAAVAAIACv//AAA=
            </data>
            <key>pageIndex</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>_BDAlias</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAFOAAIAAAhVbnRpdGxlZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADU
            QCbVSCsAAABZDB8JYWdpbGUucGRmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCb
            LdTPyHJQREYgAAAAAP////8AAAkgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABi5U
            cmFzaAAQAAgAANRAiUUAAAARAAgAANTQOPIAAAABAAwAWQwfAAYs
            xQACZv0AAgAmVW50aXRsZWQ6VXNlcnM6AG1heDoALlRyYXNoOgBh
            Z2lsZS5wZGYADgAUAAkAYQBnAGkAbABlAC4AcABkAGYADwASAAgA
            VQBuAHQAaQB0AGwAZQBkABIAGlVzZXJzL21heC8uVHJhc2gvYWdp
            bGUucGRmABMAAS8AABUAAgAK//8AAA==
            </data>
            <key>pageIndex</key>
            <integer>393</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: define "better", what is wrong with the way you already use?

Comment: It feels confusing and unreliable, generally when that's the case with ruby there's a better way :)

Comment: You could use Nokogiri, but quite honestly the solution you have looks fine to me.